# C - Ternary operate to if else

Tags: c, if-statement, ternary

Can someone help me convert this line to an if-else statement?

temp = head->left ? head->left : head->right;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( head->left )
    temp = head->left;
else
    temp = head->right;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (head->left) 
{
  temp = head->left;
}
else
{
  temp = head->right;
}
```